# Why is my XSLT formatting not working correctly in Microsoft Edge on the Windows 10 OS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xslt, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have been working on a [webpage](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/courses/crops/resource-capture-by-crops.aspx) developed in a CMS through a combination of *XSLT 1.0*, *JS* and *XML* and have come across a page rendering problem *specifically* when accessing the (ASP.NET) webpage on the **Windows 10 operating system** through the **Microsoft Edge (37.14316.1000.0) browser** (*Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14316*).

**The Problem:**

[image]

(Screenshot Captured from a Virtual Machine, using the before-mentioned conditions)

As you can clearly see, when you access my webpage using the before-mentioned conditions, the course page structure is broken up. It appears as though my [XSLT file](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/stylesheets/xslt/course-info-page-template.xslt) isn't being executed properly and a conflict is going on somewhere? This is majorly frustrating as the XSLT/JS/XML page works perfectly in all the previous Internet Explorer browser versions (all the way down to 7) plus the other leading modern browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

Maddeningly, the page actually works on **Windows 10 version 10.0.10240 Build 10240 Edge 20.10240.16384.0**, but I believe this was the previous Edge browser release, so somewhere between the last browser version and this one, this rendering problem has suddenly surfaced?

The [JS file](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/js/course-info-template.js) which calls my XSLT/XML files using the [XSLT/XML on the Client](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) method is obviously working, as data is appearing within the page, but something is not right and I'm struggling to identify what is causing the issue?

I have tried playing about with the main [CSS file](http://www.agrifoodatp.ac.uk/aatp/stylesheets/course-info-page.css) but have ruled this out as the underlying cause.

Interestingly when going into the source code of my page through the in-built Edge development tools, I managed to identify that if I removed the `form1` reference on `line 55`, just inside the opening `<body>` tag (i.e. `<form method="post" action="/aatp/courses/crops/resource-capture-by-crops.aspx" id="form1">`), the page instantly fixes itself and renders out properly, as experienced on all the other internet browsers.

[image]

Crazy??

Perhaps this `POST <form1>` call is in direct conflict with the `GET` request made by my JS file? The `form1` call is a consequence of our CMS architecture, since our web pages are effectively one big form, so I can't get rid of this 'CMS produced code'.

Any suggestions or ideas for a fix would be greatly appreciated and welcomed!

Comment: Does it improve things if you put `<xsl:output method="html"/>` in the XSLT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convince Edge that the stylesheet creates HTML elements by putting `<xsl:output method="html"/>` into your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Martin's solution (adding `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to the XSLT files) has solved this problem and the pages are rendering out perfectly in Windows 10 on the Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: where shall we add that

Comment: @BKM: the declaration `<xsl:output method="html"/>` belongs into your XSLT code, as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` root element. See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVr for a minimal example or consult any XSLT tutorial. If you have questions on your own, consider to ask them separately, with all details in a new question.

Comment: In a document containing `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>` Edge 118.0.2088.46 displays just an empty page, while Firefox displays it correctly, and even old Internet Explorer loads the HTML.

Comment: @U.Windl, consider to raise that as a separate question, with minimal but complete details to allow others to reproduce it, to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: @MartinHonnen You could use https://stackoverflow.com/q/77416484/6607497 as an example